# Autostart video from modal without using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've created a modal which is supposed to show a youtube video when page loads. The problem is that I don't want to trigger this modal with a button, I simply want it to show up when page loads and auto play this video.
I made something but the video is not showing up when the modal appears...

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-theVideo="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g9-66737t1c"></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div>
                    <iframe width="100%" height="350" src=""></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#videoModal').modal('show');

autoPlayYouTubeModal();

function autoPlayYouTubeModal() {
  var theModal = $('#videoModal').data("target"),
      videoSRC = $('#videoModal').attr("data-theVideo"),
      videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1";
  $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
  $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
  });
  $('.modal').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r4n49db4/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding `https://www.youtube.com/embed/g9-66737t1c` to `iframe` `src` attribute